# Android notify , wait not working

Tags: android

I am trying to implement synchronized method to my Android application. My notify() is not working. Here is my code and it would be helpful if someone could pinpoint me to the right direction.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
int midx ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    synchronized (this){
        doMenu(0);
        notify();
    }
}
public void doMenu(int midx) {
    synchronized (this) {
        while (midx >=0) {
            switch (midx) {
                case Constants.MENU_TYPE_SPLASH:
                    Intent m_sp = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Splash.class);
                    m_sp.putExtra("main_index_value", midx);
                    startActivityForResult(m_sp, Constants.REQUEST_RESULT_CODE);
                    break;
                case Constants.MENU_TYPE_MAIN:
                    Intent m_mm = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainMenu.class);
                    m_mm.putExtra("main_index_value", midx);
                    startActivityForResult(m_mm, Constants.REQUEST_RESULT_CODE);
                    break;
            }
        }
        try {
            wait();
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == Constants.REQUEST_RESULT_CODE) {
        synchronized (this) {
            midx = data.getIntExtra("index_value", 0);
        }
        notify();
        }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually what you are doing is wrong. if you want to do a method call after `onActivityResult()`. Set a callback and invoke that later. Currently you are blocking the main (UI) thread. Which may result in [ANR](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html). Why do you block the current execution to wait for another class. Reconsider the technique. Still want to proceed with the same technique. Your entire code is in a single thread. you may consider using wait and notify in different threads, so that it may work